# Netsuite suitetalk - how to fetch audit trail via Web service

Tags: c#, netsuite, suitetalk

I am trying to use the Netsuite Web Service to fetch the audit trail for a custom object.Ie. when was a field updated? what was the old value and the new value etc

I've checked the netsuite documentation but very quiet on the audit trail stuff

Answer (score 0):

Create a search for whatever record you want and join it to the System Notes field.